How to differentiate index entries using the knowledge package
I'm using the knowledge package to mark definitions and simplify the creation of an index.
My entries are all defined as in the following example:
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage[paper,makeidx]{knowledge}
\makeindex

\knowledge{index style=textbf,index=time!sidereal}
 | sidereal time
 | Sidereal time
\knowledge{index style=textbf,index=time!solar}
 | solar time
 | Solar time

\begin{document}
\intro{Sidereal time} is defined as a thing.
\newpage
If you remember, \kl{sidereal time} is a thing.
\newpage
Stuff\index{time} is still a thing. \kl{Solar time} is something else.

\printindex

\end{document}

This results in the following index entry:
time, 3

sidereal, 1, 2


solar, 2

The \intro term for "sidereal time" is on page 1, while the remaining references are a \kl entry and a simple \index entry.
There's no \intro term (i.e. a definition) for "solar time".
I would like the \intro terms to be the only ones referenced in bold.
I found this customization example in the knowledge package documentation but it changes both \intro and \kl:
\def\knowledgeIntroIndexStyle#1{\fbox{#1}}

How can I differentiate the \intro style (automatically or even only partially automatically)?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

To clarify, why I'm using the knowledge package: it allows me to mark definitions in my textbook (I have hundreds) just with the \intro, then I periodically populate the preamble with the intros list from a .diagnose file created by the package; then with a bit of vim magic I get a proper list and a working index mid-draft without the hassle of writing single \index entries (that will happen later to finalize the index).

The command \knowledgeIntroIndexStyle is defined by the knowledge package, but I didn't find where it is used it in its source code.

@jlab in fact it's not described in the documentation either and I thought a counterpart kl style might exist too

@armaninux kl style is set by the style key (see documentation, section 3.3.4
Knowledge styles and the \knowledgestyle command).

It works if you set it through a style. Define the style
\knowledgestyle{indexbf}{index style=textbf}

and use it as intro style
\knowledge{intro style=indexbf, index=time!sidereal}
...

Note that you can also set it by default
\knowledgedefault*{intro style=indexbf}

Full example:

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper,makeidx]{knowledge}
\makeindex

\knowledgestyle{indexbf}{index style=textbf}
\knowledgedefault*{intro style=indexbf}

\knowledge{index=time!sidereal}
 | sidereal time
 | Sidereal time
\knowledge{index=time!solar}
 | solar time
 | Solar time

\begin{document}
\intro{Sidereal time} is defined as a thing.
\newpage
If you remember, \kl{sidereal time} is a thing.
\newpage
Stuff\index{time} is still a thing. \kl{Solar time} is something else.

\printindex

\end{document}


